# Expression evaluation in C

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, expression-evaluation

Why does the following piece of C code print `12 12 12`

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  int a = 2, *f1, *f2;
  f1 = f2 = &a;
  *f2 += *f2 += a += 2.5;
  printf("%i %i %i\n", a, *f1, *f2);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The ***real*** question is why do you write code like this ?

Comment: interview-question :P, will add that tag too. Sadly, it irritates me that they ask stuff like this.

Comment: At least this useless-UB-question-of-the-week has a little bit of variety to it...

Comment: I hope their point in asking the question was for you to reply that the code has undefined behavior and that even if it didn't, it's offensively obfuscated and should never be written...

Comment: i agree, but there's nothing i can do and NO there was no option called "Undefined Behavior"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
*f2 += *f2 += a += 2.5;
```

This line has [Undefined Behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because you change the value of `*f2`(i.e. `a`) more than once within the same expression without an intervening sequence point. UB means that your program may print "Hello World", it may crash, it may print `12 12 12` or `12 12 1029` or it may start eating your brains. Don't rely on undefined behavior.

To quote the C++ standard ( I know the question is tagged C, but I don't have a C standard by me and I know the same rule holds in C)

> Except where noted, the order of evaluation of operands of individual operators and subexpressions of individual
>   expressions, and the order in which side effects take place, is unspecified.53) Between the previous
>   and next sequence point a scalar object shall have its stored value modified at most once by the evaluation
>   of an expression. Furthermore, the prior value shall be accessed only to determine the value to be stored.
>   The requirements of this paragraph shall be met for each allowable ordering of the subexpressions of a full
>   expression; otherwise the behavior is ***undefined***.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to explain the reason of the downvote?

Comment: I didnt down vote you, but I honestly would because of the cocky attitude you have on this post. Commenting on valid answers with "actually your wrong, its this" deserves to get a smack in the ego. Especially when you really didn't even answer the question, Peter did, you just quoted a standard and called it "magic"

Comment: @SomeoneRandom: I did answer the question. Peter has just guessed. I hope that some day you'll understand that a language is its standard and nothing else. In the meantime, feel free to vote me down as much as you like

Comment: Your answer was "i don't know, its random it could be anything" that is not true at all, it will produce the same result every time. Yes the language is defined by its standard, but he didn't ask anything about that, he wanted an explanation as to why it produced what it did. Hence, you did not answer the question.

Comment: @SomeoneRandom: "I don't know, its random it could be anything" ***is*** the correct answer. "It will produce the same result every time" is not true. The result of an expression that violates the rule I quoted in my answer usually varies depending on the optimization level, for example.

Answer (score 1):

It prints out the same value for all because you are only pointing to one `int` variable: `a`.

It prints out `12` because `a + 2.5 = 4` (`a` is an `int`), and then you add it to itself twice.

---

@Downvoters: Why so negative?  I think my answer says what *this compiler* is doing on *this example code*, which should help the OP understand the behaviour.  I agree that [Armen Tsirunyan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/469935/armen-tsirunyan)'s  answer is right (i.e. should get the tick) and that the [behaviour is undefined according to the standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802072/expression-evaluation-in-c/6802092#6802092).  But standards are implemented, and I've yet to see a compiler that compiles code and then, at run-time, suddenly throws up its hands and says `Undefined behaviour!`.

Comment: It's undefined behavior, actually

Comment: By the standard, yes. I was just saying what _this example_  appears to be doing.  I agree that the OP needs to understand that it's undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

I because `*f2` and `*f1` point to `a` (an integer).

So `*f2 = &a = 2` and `*f1 = &a = 2`

At this point you add to a the value of `2.5` (because `a` is an integer, you'll obtain `4`).

Than you have

```
a = 4
f2 = 4
f1 = 4
```

At this point you do `f2+f1+a = 12.`

Comment: It's undefined behavior, actually